# Soft Keyboard Style in Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Is there any option to force soft keyboard normal style ? *I mean* - when soft keyboard is `"normal style"` everything looks fine, but when user has `"split style"` in his device keyboard covers half of edit text's. I've tried to set up windowSoftInputMode but nothin' works. Any idea, please ?

Answer (score 1):

Add following in manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

[please follow the link](http://blog.vogella.com/2010/10/25/android-windowsoftinputmode/)